# PHP style changer not working

Tags: php

Please note that I'm not very good with PHP, and I did browse the web to find my answer, and I was unable to find it, so I decided to ask it here!

I have two CSS files: black.css and white.css ; the default one is black.css, and I want to be able to change to the white and back if needed.
This is my link to the stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="User Defined Style" `href="<?php echo (!$sitestyle)?'black':$sitestyle ?>.css" />`
```

This is my HTML code: (Found in index.php)

```
<a href="switcher.php?set=white">
click here to change to WHITE style!</a>
```

This is my PHP code: (Found in switcher.php)

```
<?php
setcookie ('sitestyle', $set, time()+31536000, '/', 'mydomain.com/', '0');
header("Location: $HTTP_REFERER");
?>
```

When attempting to switch styles, it gives me an error saying 'The page isn't redirecting properly'.

Comment: What is `$HTTP_REFERER`? How are you setting that variable? How does it receive its value? Note - it's a hint.

Comment: How about $_GET['set'] instead of $set?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
setcookie ('sitestyle', $_GET['set'], time()+31536000, '/', 'mydomain.com[Censored :P]/', '0');
header("Location: $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]");
?>
```

Comment: This didn't work :(
It just refreshed my page without any results.

Comment: header("Location: {$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]}");

Comment: @wormhit Curly braces aren't needed for this case. If you do use curly braces, then you need to quote `'HTTP_REFERER'`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to refer to other page but do everything on the same page:

```
//index.php

<?
   if(isset($_GET['set']))
       setcookie ('sitestyle', $_GET['set'], time()+31536000, '/', 'mydomain.com[Censored :P]/', '0');
?>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="User Defined Style"    href="<?php echo (!$sitestyle)?'black':$sitestyle ?>.css" />
```

click here to change to WHITE style!

And use better $_SESSION[''] instead of the cookies.)